# How I can use videoview from rtmp?

Tags: android, rtmp, android-video-player

How I can play the video on android from url. The url is : (e.g)

rtmp://fms.1B3E.sample.mp4

.When I want to make this the videoplayer on android says me this cant play.
How I can do this.?

Comment: Hello, i have same problem, i have same url just like yours. can u help please, if you have done this streaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Media..

**Network Protocols**

The following network protocols are supported for audio and video playback:

- RTSP (RTP, SDP)
- HTTP/HTTPS progressive streaming
- HTTP/HTTPS live streaming draft protocol:

  ```
  MPEG-2 TS media files only
  Protocol version 3 (Android 4.0 and above)
  Protocol version 2 (Android 3.x)
  Not supported before Android 3.0
  ```

Note: HTTPS is not supported before Android 3.1.

**EDIT:**

Oh Sorry... I forgot to mentioned

[**Android RTMP library**](http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-RTMP-library.shtml)

**RTMP** Library provides the implementation of the **RTMP** protocol on Android with interfaces for streaming online audio and video contents. Application can have direct control over media buffers enabling integration with third party or proprietary DRM solutions. The library also facilitates support for range of audio video codec. It offers publishing of live audio using which android based audio chat; public announcing system etc can be developed. The library is integrated with Adobe Flash Media Server family products.

Comment: For more info look at [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: so rtmp is supported from android-media?

Comment: No.. rtsp is supported..

Comment: thanks for answering.Last of my questions : How I make live video stream in android? it is possible?

Comment: @ersin gülbahar - Just look at this library and let me know what happen in your case..

Comment: I look the library but the download link is broken

Comment: @ersin gülbahar - K, Let me check it If I will find any update then post it here. You will also check this post.

Comment: And again thanks for answering. But I dont understand how I can use this library to rtmp live stream videos play on android.

Comment: You have to find any example for it.

Comment: ok.thanks I am looking for it

Comment: welcome..! I will also look for it.

Comment: Library is not available..Link is broken.. How can I do this?

Comment: @user370305 is this library open source?? I did read it on their site though that one can load about 2mb of files, but it couldnt make things any clear.